# MongoError: MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
//const uri = "mongodb+srv://test:test@sos-nwznc.mongodb.net/sos?retryWrites=true";
const uri = "mongodb+srv://test:<test>@sos-lriv2.mongodb.net/sos?retryWrites=true";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });

var contacts;

client.connect(err => {
  contacts = client.db("sos1819").collection("contacts");
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Tengo este código y me sale error cuando ejecuto la base de datos, he revisado mil veces la coleccion , base de datos y usuario y está bien , no sé en que puede estar fallando.

***MongoError: MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db***

Comment: sí , sí , es Javascript

Comment: Tu código funciona perfectamente en mis pruebas

Comment: Pues a mí no me funciona

Comment: Extraño. ¿Qué versión de Node usas? Yo uso 11.11

Comment: Otra cosa, intenta usar el callback tal cual lo sugiere la documentación. `client.connect((err, db) => {/* tu codigo*/));` Aunque tal como lo tienes funciona, al menos a mi me funciona y logro conectarme a la uri que colocas en tu codigo.

Comment: Prueba lo siguiente, en lugar de usar `client.connect` usa `client.open((err, client) => {/* tu codigo aqui*/}));`. Dentro de tu callback realizas las operaciones con `client`. Más info en la [documentación](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html)

Comment: Me dice que que la funcion open no es una función

Comment: No sé si debe a la cloud de mongodb o no sé pero he probado todo ya

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91440/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-royalup).